# Mailx Command Attempts to Send mail to Server/Node

Tags: bash, shell, mailx

I am new to using BASH/Shell scripts and am trying to learn the best I can and have run into a small inconvience when using the mailx command.

Currently I use mailx command to send an email with attached CSV file once the process is complete.  I use "-r" to set the from box as our groups email from Outlook

```
-r TeamName@example.com
```

This works fine and the email goes out and says it's from the team box. One thing that happens is we also get an undeliverable message in our box as it appears to be trying to send one to the server the mailx is on

```
Unable to send mail. Message from host node.server.example.com. Then it shows the email as:
-@node.server.example.com
```

Since the company controls the servers and environment I can make no changes to the settings or anything like that. But is there anything I can do that will stop us from having our mailbox being cluttered up with all of the undeliverable messages?

Current mail command I am using:

```
echo "This is the body of the email.  There is stuff here.
Thank you for reading this.
Team Member" | mailx -r teammail@example.com -s "Email Subject" -a "filename.csv" - email1@example.com email2@example.com email3@example.com
```

Comment: Please present an example of a full command that you're using to send mail.  Also, have you confirmed that the mail you're sending is actually getting through to the intended recipients?

Comment: I updated with the code I have that works.  It sends the email with the attachment the from is corectly the team mailbox, and all recepients get the email. I just also get an email saying it couldn't send it to "-@node.server.name.com".  It has a "-"before the @ symbol then everything after the @ symbol is what shows when I log into PUTTY to run the commands; from my understanding that is the node I connect to.

Comment: You have a lone `-` on the command line.  Many utilities, when receiving that where they expect a file name, will read from the standard input.  But `mailx` already reads from the standard input, and it expects an *address* there, not a file name.  An address without an `@` is interpreted as a local username, which is why `mailx` attempts to send to `-@node.server.name.com`.  Just remove that bare `-`.

Comment: fwiw, [`example.com`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2606#section-2),etc exist for things like this. Both `email.com` and `node.server.name.com` are real hosts

Comment: Thank you I was not aware, I updated accordingly.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Thank you so much.  I am really new to this, and the example I used to learn how to do the mailx had the - before the emails, and it made sense to me because of the -r -s -a throughout so I thought - meant the email addreses were to follow. It never dawned on me that the - was trying to be used as an email and thats why the - was before the @ in the error mail.  Thank you for taking the time to answer and not makign me feel dumb for such a simple mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to John above I was able to fix this issue.  Mailx was reading the - before the email addresses as a user name on the server and trying to send to -@server.example.com.  I have removed the - and tested a few different jobs and I no longer receive the error emails.